# Query to return data based on days

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a very simple data set and I am trying to figure out how to return a data set broken up into day increments.

```
Order_id [int], date_created [dateTime]
```

We are using SQL Server 2012

Whilst the query is quite simple to fetch the data

```
SELECT order_id, date_created 
FROM orders
```

I have been returning this data then manipulating it with coldfusion functions to organise the return data into separate arrays so the transactions were calculated by date.

What I'm trying to do is return the data as a data set of the last 7 days based on the `date_created` column.

So the result set is

```
Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday
```

with all the returned transactions for those days under it.

My SQL skills are very basic, and I've been hunting online for a possible solution so I can separate this from the application and keep it within a query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use datename to do this.

```
   DECLARE @date_created datetime = GETDATE()

   SELECT datename(dw,@date_created)
   SELECT datename(dw,@date_created - 1)
   SELECT datename(dw,@date_created - 2)
   SELECT datename(dw,@date_created - 3)
   SELECT datename(dw,@date_created - 4)
   SELECT datename(dw,@date_created - 5)
   SELECT datename(dw,@date_created - 6)
```

Replace @date_created with your variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @yourDate DATETIME = GETDATE()
SELECT DATENAME(WEEKDAY, @yourDate) -- Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, etc., etc
SELECT DATENAME(M, @yourDate) -- January, February, etc., etc.
```

---

The following example returns the date parts for the specified date.

SELECT DATENAME(datepart,'2007-10-30 12:15:32.1234567 +05:10')

datepart | Return value

*year, yyyy, yy*  | 2007

*quarter, qq, q* | 4

*month, mm, m* | October

*dayofyear, dy, y* | 303

*day, dd, d* | 30

*week, wk, ww* | 44

*weekday, dw* | Tuesday

*hour, hh* | 12

*minute, n* | 15

*second, ss, s* | 32

*millisecond, ms* | 123

*microsecond, mcs*| 123456

*nanosecond, ns* | 123456700

*TZoffset, tz* | 310

---

Please visit [Microsoft TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for more information about it.